# how can I change the certificate of remote desktop?

Tags: windows, certificate, ssl-certificate, remote-desktop

When I try to connect to a computer with remote desktop, I get an warning that say that the certificate is emitted by an untrusted author, but anyway I can connect.

I have my p12 certificate that I create with openssl and I would like to know how to change the certificate for remote desktop in the remote computer, because the certificate which I have problems is the name of the computer, and has the same emisor. I would like to use the certificate that I have created instead of the default certificate.

I am using windows 8 pro in the remote computer and the computer from I try to connect uses windows 7 (in a virtual machine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, find the thumbprint of your certificate:

```
Get-Childitem Cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

Then, run this WMI command (make sure to replace Thumbprint with your certificate's):

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\CIMV2\TerminalServices PATH Win32_TSGeneralSetting Set SSLCertificateSHA1Hash="Thumbprint"
```

Comment: Note: Your certificate must be in the Personal store or you will get an error.